# Modify Excel file in ASP.NET "on the fly"

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, editing, on-the-fly

> **EDIT**
>   This question is no more justified because I can now save the Excel files on the server.
>   But thanks to everyone for the answers!

I am writing an ASP.NET application in which a user uploads an Excel file.
I have to edit it and generated pictures "on the fly" (meaning no storage) then zip the Excel files with the pictures and send it back to the user.

My problem is that I don't know how to edit the Excel file that has been sent then send it back with the exact same name...

Here is the controller handling the upload of the file:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PoliteUpload(HttpPostedFileBase UserFile)
    {
        String viewReturned = "Polite";
        if (UserFile != null && UserFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            TempData["MessageTitle"] = @Resource.ExtensionOkTitle;
            TempData["Message"] = @Resource.ExtensionOk;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(UserFile.FileName);
            if (extension.Equals(".xls"))
            {
                 //Old version ok
            }
            else if (extension.Equals(".xlsx"))
            {
                 //Current version ok
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = true;
                TempData["Message"] = @Resource.ExtensionKo;
                TempData["MessageTitle"] = @Resource.ExtensionKoTitle;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Error"] = true;
            TempData["MessageTitle"] = @Resource.NoFileTitle;
            TempData["Message"] = @Resource.NoFile;
        }
        return RedirectToAction(viewReturned);
    }
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you use CSV format instead of XLS or XLSX?  It is really simple to read.  XLSX should be XML format, so you could parse it using the syntax that XLSX supports.  You can use the Excel API but then licensing is required for that...

Comment: You will also have to take into consideration the memory usage when processing all this in memory.

Comment: instead of doing `extension.Equals` you can look at the content type. there is one for new and old excel versions

Comment: @BrianMains There are plenty of open source libraries capable of reading and manipulating XLSX files, no license required. [Office XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/), and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) come to mind.

Comment: @mason Thanks good to know.  XLSX is much easier since it's a more normalized, XML-based format, but OP mentioned XLS too.  Thanks for the links!

Comment: @BrianMains I have to handle CSV, XLS, XLSX, TXT, MDB and ACCDB but I have to begin with XLS and XLSX.

Comment: @CallumLinington This will be handled after, all I want now in local is to know how to edit files "on the fly" without storing them on my server.

Comment: @mason Thank you! I'll have a look at these libraries :)